# Adding custom property to any control

Tags: wpf, xaml

For example, we have `TextBlock` control, how can I add to it my own property, it's may looks like
`<TextBlock MyProperty="666"/>`
Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for attached properties? http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/10/12/how-to-create-an-attached-properties-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), that's exactly what they're here for.

The code won't look exactly as in your example, though, but rather like this:

```
<TextBlock my:MyClass.MyProperty="666"></TextBlock>
```

(`my` is the XML namespace prefix for the namespace where `MyClass` is declared)